# What does \,^@ means in a sed expression

Tags: sed

I came across this code `sed '\,^@, s/ABC/XYZ/' filename`
What does `\,^@,` means here. I thought `comma ,` operator defines the line range on which substitute expression will operate.

Comment: `\,` means `,` is regex delimiter instead of usual `/`... `^@` to match `@` at beginning of line... `,` to end the match... `s/ABC/XYZ/` to perform substitutions only on lines matching `@` at beginning of line...

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace

Comment: Thanks Sundeep, sorry but I am still not clear. I understood ^@ denotes lines starting with @.  Are you saying \, means alternate regex delimeter , then shouldn't it be just ,@, or \,@\,. Thanks

Comment: @CppLearner for substitute commands, `s,foo,baz,` will work.. but for address matching, you need extra ``\`` at start...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the `man` page, *In a context address, the construction "\cBREc", where c is any character  other than backslash   or newline, shall be identical to "/BRE/".* So your script is identical to

```
sed '/^@/ s/ABC/XYZ/' filename
```

which means the replacement is only to be done in lines starting with `@`

Comment: Perfect Philippos. This is what I was looking for thanks a lot for your help and explanation. Upvoting and accepting this as answer. Thank you.